# Mouse goes crazy

Tags: windows-7, mouse

I have a weird problem with my mouse pointer whereby the pointer moves upwards and downwards by itself. I have checked the mouse settings and these are normal. I didn't download any free cursor from the internet.

Does someone have an explanation for this please?

Comment: It would be useful if you gave some details, such as OS, mouse brand/version info, etc.

Answer (score 0):

If its wireless, get the batteries out and put them back in.
Check your drivers, update/reinstall them.
Check the mouse for a hair or something small on the path of the laser.
Check what happens if you plug in another mouse.

Comment: If your batteries and everything else is fine, check what frequency your mouse operated at - other devices could be interfering with the wireless signal. A quick Google search would probably return some results about whether this is a common problem (I would have Googled but you didn't specify the mouse make and model)